# Alternative applications for Cisco VPN client on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, cisco-vpn-client

I use Cisco Systems' VPN Client v5.0 on Windows 7 to connect to my work environment. My VPN profile is available as a PCF file. I would occasionally like to use Ubuntu 10.10. Are there any applications that support connecting to a VPN server from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

If you install the `network-manager-vpnc` and then `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` or `network-manager-vpnc-kde` packages, you'll have a GUI config interface for setting up a Cisco-compatible VPN connection using  `vpnc` (more info on it is at http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/ ).

You may also want to install the `vpnc` package in order to get a `pcf2vpnc` utility that'll try to convert the PCF file over.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, after restarting Network Manager.  +1

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall the built-in network manager has support for Cisco VPNs, once the correct package is installed.

Try:

```
apt-cache search network | grep manager -i
```

I believe the package is something like "networkmanager-cisco".

Once that is installed, you should be able to add a VPN connection using the normal network manager window.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the network-manager-vpnc and network-manager-vpnc-gnome packages, I kept getting the error:

```
 The VPN connection 'xxxxx' failed because there were no valid VPN secrets.
```

It turns out that the solution to that problem is to [restart the Network Manager](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10256268&postcount=18)

```
  sudo restart network-manager
  sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

After following the answer provided by @Cos, and following the restart instructions, my VPN is now functioning.

Answer (score 1):

[vpnc](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/) is the VPN choice for me. It's pretty simple to use through the command line (which I am assuming you are comfortable with or at least interested in using since you use Ubuntu).

The following should work fine:

```
sudo apt-get install vpnc
```

If not, you can install from source: 
http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/vpnc-0.5.3.tar.gz